# Прозрачность background слоев

Tags: html, css

Есть слой с фоном в виде картинки

на него сверху накладывается слой побольше с фоном тоже в виде полупрозрачной картинки формата png

в итоге через наложенный слой 2 не проступает слой 1

с чем это может быть связано?

картинка полупрозрачная

[image]
нужно использовать css2 поэтому свойство прозрачности для слоев исключаю

и главное, если фон слоя убрать и сделать вместо него картинку то через картинку нормально проступает слой 1

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj поподробнее!  
1 В каком браузере?!  
2

 > и главное, если фон слоя убрать и сделать вместо него картинку то через картинку нормально проступает слой 1

 сделать картинку то есть заменить `div` или другой тег с фоном на тег `img` с `src` равным бывшему `background-image: url();` у замененого тега?!

Comment: в div 2 вставить картинку и убрать фоновый стиль тогда все работает

Comment: использовал background:url(../../images/bg.png) left top repeat-x #ffffff;

все дело оказалось в #ffffff

это очень плохо с точки зрения верстки, придется делать 2 слоя а можно было бы обойтись одним